# How to point sonarqube Azure Devops pipeline to scan a different branch in another repo?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, branch

I have a separate pipeline in Azure Devops for sonar analysis, which scans another repo in Azure Devops, however, it is only scanning the master branch, I would like it to scan specific branches, ideally, all feature branches or just our test branch.

I've tried a few things but unable to get this working, here is part of my sonar pipeline code (removed/changed any names/sensitive info):

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: platform-code
    type: git
    name: platform-code
  #pipelines:
  #   - pipeline: platform-build
  #     source: platform-build
  #     trigger:
  #      branches:
   #        - feature/awesomeaddition


#trigger:
#  branches:
#    include:
#    - master
#    - features/*

stages:

- stage: Sonarqube
  variables:
    - template: variables.yaml
  jobs:
    - job: SonarqubeScan
      steps:
        - checkout: self
        - checkout: platform-code
  
        - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
          displayName: 'SonarQube Prepare'
          inputs:
            SonarQube: ${{ variables.SonarQubeServiceConnectionName }}
            scannerMode: 'CLI'
            configMode: 'manual'
            cliProjectKey: ${{ variables.cliProjectKey }}
            cliProjectName: ${{ variables.cliProjectName }}
            cliSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platform-build'
            extraProperties: |
              sonar.branch.name='feature/awesomeaddition'
```

Comment: I assume you have the developer/enterprise version of sonarqube yes? Because in the community edition it only scans the master branch